# Video does not load in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, video

This is a rather strange bug, when you turn on the PC and go to chrome, the videos are played, but after some time, further playback is not available. I would put up with it, but when this bug occurs, I lose the ability to reboot or turn off the PC. That is, if I write `shutdown -h now` or `shutdown -r now` or `reboot` in the terminal, I will get a black screen with a blinking cursor and that's it. Yes, the problem is strange, but I hope you will help me figure it out.
So here the logs:

```
13:24:24 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1017] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Logs'
13:24:23 gnome-calendar: source_credentials_required_cb: Failed to authenticate 'Праздники России': Failed to obtain an access token for “Праздники России”: Не удалось найти учётные данные в связке ключей
13:24:22 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1017] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Calendar'
13:24:22 systemd: Started Time & Date Service.
13:24:22 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
13:24:22 systemd: Starting Time & Date Service...
13:24:22 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.timedate1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.timedate1.service' requested by ':1.112' (uid=1000 pid=12578 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-calendar --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
13:24:22 systemd: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
13:24:22 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1017] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
13:24:21 systemd: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
13:24:21 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1017] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.44' (uid=1000 pid=1433 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
13:24:21 gnome-shell: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
13:23:42 Telegram: qt.gui.imageio.jpeg: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
13:23:32 gnome-shell: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
13:23:29 Telegram: qt.gui.imageio.jpeg: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
13:23:07 systemd: Finished Message of the Day.
13:20:55 gnome-shell: pushModal: invocation of begin_modal failed
13:18:16 Telegram: qt.gui.imageio.jpeg: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
13:17:18 gnome-shell: pushModal: invocation of begin_modal failed
13:17:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
13:17:01 sh: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
13:17:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
13:17:00 Telegram: qt.gui.imageio.jpeg: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
13:10:00 gnome-shell: pushModal: invocation of begin_modal failed
13:07:23 Telegram:   OpenType support missing for "davazirmedium", script 18
13:07:07 gnome-shell: unable to update icon for discord1
13:04:46 wpa_supplicant: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-60 noise=9999 txrate=585000
13:03:21 gnome-shell: pushModal: invocation of begin_modal failed
13:02:57 Telegram: qt.gui.imageio.jpeg: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
13:02:48 gnome-shell: pushModal: invocation of begin_modal failed
13:02:21 Discord: [2022-01-07 13:02:21.160] [5992] (audio_device_generic.cc:32): BuiltInAECIsAvailable: Not supported on this platform
13:02:18 gnome-shell: pushModal: invocation of begin_modal failed
13:01:17 wpa_supplicant: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-63 noise=9999 txrate=26000
13:01:16 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
13:01:16 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired.
13:01:13 gnome-shell: pushModal: invocation of begin_modal failed
12:54:28 Telegram: qt.gui.imageio.jpeg: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
12:51:10 systemd: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
12:51:01 whoopsie: [12:51:01] online
12:51:00 NetworkManager: <info>  [1641549060.2430] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
12:50:59 systemd: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
12:50:59 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
12:50:59 whoopsie: [12:50:59] offline
12:50:59 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.16' (uid=0 pid=837 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
12:50:59 systemd: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
12:50:59 NetworkManager: <info>  [1641549059.9649] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
12:50:43 goa-daemon: /org/gnome/OnlineAccounts/Accounts/account_1640857403_0: Setting AttentionNeeded to FALSE because EnsureCredentials() succeded

12:50:43 gnome-keyring-d: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/_d0_a1_d0_b2_d1_8f_d0_b7_d0_ba_d0_b0_5f_d0_ba_d0_bb_d1_8e_d1_87_d0_b5_d0_b9_5f_d0_bf_d0_be_5f_d1_83_d0_bc_d0_be_d0_bb_d1_87_d0_b0_d0_bd_d0_b8_d1_8e/1, but it's already registered
12:50:42 gnome-shell: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
12:50:02 Telegram: qt.gui.imageio.jpeg: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
```

Comment: Create a Live CD (take a flash drive, download Ubuntu 21.10 or 20.04 LTS, put it on the flash drive (I suggest [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/)), boot to the flash drive, and press Try Ubuntu). Install Chrome there, and see if you can reproduce the issue there. Then, [edit] your question with the results. You can get back to normal Ubuntu by shutting down the live CD, unplugging the USB, and when you turn the computer on, normal Ubuntu will be back

Comment: Do you have a corrupted filesystem? I would check your logs, and look for anything suspicious.